# Is the following process a martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Is the following process a martingale?

Let $X$ denotes a process defined by the following: $$X_{t}=\sigma_{t} W_{t},$$ where $W$ is a Wiener process, $\sigma_{t}=\begin{cases}
1.1 & \text{if}\;X_{t}-X_{t-1}>0\\
0.9 & \text{if}\;X_{t}-X_{t-1}\leq0\\
1 & \text{if}\;t\in\left[0,1\right]
\end{cases}$. I wanted to check if $X$ whether a martingale or not, by the definition of the martingale.

If $t\in\left[0,1\right]$, then it is clear $X=W$ is a martingale, I have bigger problems with the   $1<s<t-1$ and $1<t-1\leq s\leq t$ cases.

I also think if $1<s\leq t-1$, then $X_{t}-X_{s}$ is independent from $\mathcal{F}_{s}$, but I am not certain in this statement. If this is the case, then $$\mathbb{E}\left[X_{t}\mid\mathcal{F}_{s}\right] =\mathbb{E}\left(\sigma_{t}W_{t}-\sigma_{s}W_{s}+\sigma_{s}W_{s}\mid\mathcal{F}_{s}\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\sigma_{t}W_{t}-\sigma_{s}W_{s}\right)+\sigma_{s}W_{s}=$$

$$=\mathbb{E}\left(\sigma_{t}W_{t}\right)-\mathbb{E}\left(\sigma_{s}W_{s}\right)+\sigma_{s}W_{s}=\ldots,$$ where $$\mathbb{E}\left(\sigma_{t}W_{t}\right) =\mathbb{E}\left(\sigma_{t}W_{t}\cdot1\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\sigma_{t}W_{t}\cdot\left(\chi_{\left\{ X_{t}-X_{t-1}>0\right\} }+\chi_{\left\{ X_{t}-X_{t-1}\leq0\right\} }\right)\right)=$$

$$=\mathbb{E}\left(\sigma_{t}W_{t}\chi_{\left\{ X_{t}-X_{t-1}>0\right\} }\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(\sigma_{t}W_{t}\chi_{\left\{ X_{t}-X_{t-1}\leq0\right\} }\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(1.1W_{t}\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(0.9W_{t}\right)=0.$$ So $$\mathbb{E}\left[X_{t}\mid\mathcal{F}_{s}\right]=\ldots=\mathbb{E}\left(\sigma_{t}W_{t}\right)-\mathbb{E}\left(\sigma_{s}W_{s}\right)+\sigma_{s}W_{s}=0-0+\sigma_{s}W_{s}=\sigma_{s}W_{s}.$$

I am not sure if it is true, and I still don't know the $1<t-1\leq s\leq t$ part.

Comment: I suspect this is extremely difficult using the definition of a martingale.  Is there a reason you want to verify this by definition instead of using the fact that the integral of a bounded, adapted process with respect to a Brownian motion is a martingale?

Comment: But how do I know this is an integral respect to the Brownian motion? Do you want me to use Ito's formula? It would be a good idea...I am going to try...

Comment: Ohh...I think I see the missunderstanding. By  $\cdot$ I have meant a simple multiplication, and not that $\sigma$ is integrated by $W$. Sorry for that...

Comment: Sorry, I may have misunderstood your notation.  The $\cdot$ is sometimes used to indicate integration, so I thought what you wrote meant $X_t = \int_0^t \sigma_s dW_s$.

Comment: You are absolutely right, sorry...I corrected it...

Comment: No need to be sorry, it wasn't wrong, just a misunderstanding!  Anyway, I don't think this process is well-defined.  If you consider the event $\frac{1}{1.1} W_1 < W_2 \le \frac{1}{0.9} W_1$, what should $\sigma_2$ be?  $X_1 = W_1$, so if $\sigma_2 = 1.1$ then $X_2-X_1 = 1.1 W_2 - W_1 > 0$ and it's consistent with the definition of $\sigma_t$, but if $\sigma_2 = 0.9$ then $X_2-X_1 = 0.9 W_2 - W_1 \le 0$ and it is also consistent with the definition of $\sigma_t$.

Comment: I think you are right again...How do I want to know the value of $X_{t}$ if I need the value of $\sigma_{t}$, where again I have to know the value of $X_{t}$!? Is that (or a similar thing) you wanted to say?

Comment: And what if I modify $\sigma_{t}$ as $\sigma_{t}=\begin{cases}
1.1 & \text{if}\;X_{t-1}-X_{t-2}>0\\
0.9 & \text{if}\;X_{t-1}-X_{t-2}\leq0\\
1 & \text{if}\;t\in\left[0,2\right]
\end{cases}$? Is it still not well-definied?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129176/discussion-between-user6247850-and-kapes-mate).

Comment: Jus for a last sentence: With the modification I have written above, I don't think it is a martingale, since for $t-1<s\leq t$ we have $\mathbb{E}\left(X_{t}\mid\mathcal{F}_{s}\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\sigma_{t}W_{t}\mid\mathcal{F}_{s}\right),$ and in this case $\sigma_{t}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t-1}\subset\mathcal{\mathcal{F}}_{s}$ measurable, therefore $\mathbb{E}\left(\sigma_{t}\left(W_{t}-W_{s}+W_{s}\right)\mid\mathcal{F}_{s}\right)=\sigma_{t}\mathbb{E}\left(W_{t}-W_{s}\mid\mathcal{F}_{s}\right)+\sigma_{t}W_{s}=\sigma_{t}\cdot0+\sigma_{t}W_{s}\neq\sigma_{s}W_{s}=X_{s}.$

Comment: Yes, I agree with your proof that process is not a martingale.